# How do I turn an arrow function into an if/else statement?

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement, arrow-functions

I've run into a slight problem with my toggle menu. The hamburger animation works fine, and once  a link is clicked it takes you to that section of my page, and removes my CSS helper class "lockscreen" - this hides my overflow so that you can't scroll on the toggle menu. However, if you want to look at the menu, then close it without clicking on a menu item - the "lockscreen" class remains applied. I'm a bit a JavaScript newb, do I need to event listener into an if/else statment of add a new variable/function to enable scroll if no link is click once the menu has been closed?

```
const navToggle = document.querySelector(".nav-toggle");
const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".nav__link");

navToggle.addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.body.classList.toggle("nav-open");
  document.body.classList.add("lockscreen");
});

navLinks.forEach((link) => {
  link.addEventListener("click", () => {
    document.body.classList.remove("nav-open");
    document.body.classList.remove("lockscreen");
  });
});
```

Comment: Show the html code too.

Comment: USe `toggle("lockscreen")` instead of `add("lockscreen")`?

Comment: Thank you @Barmar that worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

You could add an event listener on the body so that any clicks outside of the menu will remove the 'lockscreen', or a more complicated approach would be to use an if/else within the listener function to check if the current event.target === 'someElement'

```js
const navToggle = document.querySelector(".nav-toggle");
const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".nav__link");


navToggle.addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.body.classList.toggle("nav-open");
  document.body.classList.add("lockscreen");
});

navLinks.forEach((link) => {
  link.addEventListener("click", () => {
    document.body.classList.remove("nav-open");
    document.body.classList.remove("lockscreen");
  });
});

document.body.addEventListener("click", () => {
    document.body.classList.remove("lockscreen");
})
```

Watch out for bubbling!
Read more about propogation, capturing and bubbling [here](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing)